# Use Qt to display a block of color

Tags: qt

I want to display a 25 x 25 block of color in a QtWidget, set using a QColor instance.

There's not going to be anything else in the widget, just a rectangle of color is great. I know I can redefine the size of the widget by subclassing and reimplementing the `size` method. I don't know how to set the color.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `styleSheet` property of `QWidget`.

Example:

```
QWidget w;
w.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: rgb(201, 76, 76);}");
```